# How add Our Own Metric Expression in kibana(5.1.1)?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-5

In Metric agg. by default we have `Sum,count,avg,min,max,unique-count` etc the functions I want to add my own customized function suppose `sum/Unique_count` how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it will required a code changes. Now currently all Kibana metrics are located there - https://github.com/elastic/kibana/tree/master/src/ui/public/agg_types/metrics. So, you need to clone Kibana at first, than add `your_own_metric.js`, which will be similar to other built-in metrics. Later on, you need to add your metrics to `index.js`, under https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/master/src/ui/public/agg_types/index.js and hopefully after you will build Kibana, you could use your custom version of it.

Some additional information - https://discuss.elastic.co/t/custom-metric-aggregation-plugin/70072/8

Comment: will it be possible to implement Sum/Count function using this

Comment: @AkshayPatil, yes, i think so, you need some js knowledge however, and be able to build Kibana and use your custom artifact later on

Comment: I got this extended_metric plugin from internet but it returns only on value I want to calculate values for whole bucket how it can be achieved?